# Sign/Write on a android screen

Tags: android, scanning

I am creating an application and I want the user to be able to write/sign (their signature) on the screen.

I want the application to be able to draw out what they sign/write and create an image out of that.

How should I go about this ?

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

There's an ready-to-use Android Library project using square lib:
https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad

Same lib as @Dokumans proposal

Answer (score -2):

A way doing this is implementing a class which extends `View` and implementing the `onTouchEvent` where you have to track the touch events.

```
public class MyView extends View {
   @Override
   public void onDraw() {
     //draw the tracked path here
   }

   @Override
   Public  void onTouchEvent() {
      //track the events here
   }
}
```

You can find [here](https://corner.squareup.com/2010/07/smooth-signatures.html) an implementation.